# PHP - cast from large float to int will return 0

Tags: php, casting, floating-point, integer

I can't explain the following behaviour. When casting very large integers (which are handled as floats by PHP) with (int) I get the following results:

```
<?php
print (int)9223372036854775800;  // returns: 9223372036854775800
echo "<br />";
print (int)11702667999999911110; // returns: -6744076073709639680
echo "<br />";
print (int)17999997999999911110; // returns: -446746073709639680
echo "<br />";
print (int)18400997999999911110; // returns: -45746073709639680
echo "<br />";
print (int)41702667999999999990; // returns: 0
?>
```

Why does PHP return these values?

Comment: Perhaps that behaviour is because those large values exceed the range for a 32-bit or 64-bit (depending on which of PHP you're using) integer value

Answer (score 4):

You are exceeding the maximum so it's doing that weird stuff from the PHP.net website. You would have to check your max but that looks bigger than 9E18.

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

Comment: Yes, I know that I'm exceeding the max size. However there seems to be no consistent handling for this case as seen in my example above. Should there be a "predictable default" Behaviour when exceeding the PHP_INT_MAX?

Answer (score 1):

You are exceeding the value of [PHP_INT_MAX](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) which is the largest integer that PHP can support, which is usually 2,147,483,647 on a 32-bit system.  Larger numbers are switched over to the [float type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).